# In Python, how do I remove this white space?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
class Direction:
    def __init__(self,position=0):
        self.position=position
        self.dir=1
    def display(self):
        print("Positon:",self.position,",Direction: Up")
```

Here is what's printing now:

```
 >>> a=Direction(3)

 >>> a.display()

 Positon: 3 ,Direction: Up
```

I want to remove the space after 3.

Comment: You're not showing the code that actually does the printing. That said,  `print` adds spaces between elements being printed. You can pass `sep=''` to make the separator the empty string instead.

Comment: You can `print(..., sep='')` to remove the default space. But probably better would be to use `print("Positon: {}, Direction {}".format(self.position, ["Down", "Up"][self.dir]))` [I'm assuming `"Up"` is actually calculated from `self.dir`.

Comment: FYI, this is a duplicate of [How to print in Python without newline or space?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/493386/364696). I'd close, but I clicked the wrong option on close vote and can't fix.

Comment: You want string formatting. The comma is adding the spaces. https://pyformat.info

Answer (score 2):

Use `format`. Your `display` function would look like this:

```
def display(self):
    print("Positon: {},Direction: Up".format(self.position))

>>> a.display()

Positon: 3,Direction: Up
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
>>> print("Position: ", self.position, ", Direction: Up", sep='')
Position: 3, Direction: Up
```

Or:

```
>>> print("Position: %s, Direction: Up" % self.position)
Position: 3, Direction: Up
```

Comment: The second code doesn't print that output